# EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at SFApplication sendEvent

Tags: objective-c, uialertcontroller

Getting this error intermittently in production. Fails on objMsgSend for isKindOfClass. Having difficulty reproducing in development, would like to be able to do so. Have tried showing and dismissing the UIAlertController with other view controllers on the screen, moving to and from background etc. EDIT: Have now been able to reproduce this. Occurs when the UIAlertController appears with (shows underneath) an existing popover in the app. EDIT2: Appears to be an issue on iOS8, but less frequent although still occurring in iOS9

> Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread 0  libobjc.A.dylib
>   0x0000000194d8bbd0 objc_msgSend + 16 1  UIKit
>   0x0000000188a2d384 -[UIWindow setDelegate:] + 132 2  UIKit
>   0x0000000188cb5cd4 -[UIPresentationController
>   runTransitionForCurrentState] + 592 3  UIKit
>   0x0000000188cd1cd8 -[UIViewController
>   _dismissViewControllerWithAnimationController:interactionController:completion:]
>   + 672 4  UIKit                          0x0000000188ae0258 -[UIViewController _dismissViewControllerWithTransition:from:completion:] + 852 5  UIKit                          0x0000000188a8875c -[UIViewController
>   dismissViewControllerWithTransition:completion:] + 952 6  UIKit
>   0x0000000188a88344 -[UIViewController
>   dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:] + 252 7  UIKit
>   0x0000000188d84d7c -[UIAlertController
>   _dismissAnimated:triggeringAction:triggeredByPopoverDimmingView:] + 420 8  UIKit                          0x00000001889ac750
>   _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 8536 9  UIKit                          0x00000001889e68dc -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 1044 10 UIKit 
>   0x00000001889e5f7c -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 660 11 UIKit
>   0x00000001889b968c -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 264 12 iPath
>   0x000000010023c3cc -[SFApplication sendEvent:] (SFApplication.m:72) 13
>   UIKit                          0x0000000188c5860c
>   _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 14992 14 UIKit                          0x00000001889b7bf4 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 1616 15
>   CoreFoundation                 0x00000001841c29ec
>   **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 24 16 CoreFoundation                 0x00000001841c1c90
>   __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 264 17 CoreFoundation                 0x00000001841bfd40 __CFRunLoopRun + 712 18 CoreFoundation
>   0x00000001840ed0a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396 19 GraphicsServices
>   0x000000018d25b5a4 GSEventRunModal + 168 20 UIKit
>   0x0000000188a1eaa4 UIApplicationMain + 1488 21 iPath
>   0x00000001000ca308 main (main.m:33) 22 libdyld.dylib
>   0x00000001953e6a08 start + 4